# Sticky keys: how do I know a key is stuck?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, accessibility

I'm trying to get myself to use sticky keys (to prevent RSI), but I often find I've pressed Ctrl and then changed my mind, and I'm not sure if hitting e.g. q will insert a q or quit the program … is there a way to get an onscreen indicator for whether a key is "stuck"?

Alternatively, is there a way to get sirupy keys, ie. keys that stick when you hit them but then let go if there's no more keys within N seconds?

Comment: oh thanks :-) I gave up on sticky keys due to no indicator. I guess I'll have to figure out how to make unity-xkbmod.c work in xfce some day …

Comment: It should work, xfce has a plugin to support Unity appindicator. However xfce still support gtk tray, it will be nice if you modify it to use it instead of libappindicator. Another idea is to use an overlay window (I've read before about such thing.. may be in MAC OS).